# Thick client or a standalone application?

Tags: architecture, thick-client

I was wondering what is the exact difference between a **thick client** and a **standalone application**.

According to wikipedia a thick client still requires an application server.

I've got a .Net Windows Forms application that does not connect to an application server but still uses a database server. This application is solely an SQL provider for the db server and does not process data in a relevant way.

Is this application considered to be a **standalone** app or a **thick** client?

Edit: Is, for instance, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio a standalone application or a thick client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A standalone application can work without any network connection, but a thick client needs periodical network connection.

In your case your application requires to connect to a database server over network, so it will be called as thick client.

These terms are loosely used, so don't worry much about it.